# EF 6 Help deleting items from the Database using dbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I cant seem to find out what is going wrong here since my save works perfectly and the same concept was employed for use in the delete functionality. any help would be appreciated..

**Working Save**

```
context.Entry(tableObj).State = tableData.uid == Guid.Empty ?
                System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added :
                System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

**failing delete**

```
context.Entry(tableObj).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
        context.SaveChanges();
```

**error message** *well partial error*

```
System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary Key.
```

Comment: Does tableObj belong to that specific context instance, or was it loaded through a different instance?

Comment: @MikeCole This specific instance

Answer (score 0):

I've never deleted something by changing it's state but have you try just doing:

```
dbset.Remove(entity);
```